# Expanding query with where or filtering in formula in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have this formula which works great: `=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(JOIN(";",'TAB'!I2:I),";"))&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''",0))`

It takes values in column that are separated with `;` and counts unique entries and plots everything in a table.

**Question:** I would like to **add a filter/condition** so that it would plot only the values what have specific entries in another column. Like A or B ir C, but not all values.
I have tried: `=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(JOIN(";",'TAB'!I2:I),";"))&{"";""})&'RAW-TODOS'!F2:F,"select Col1` * where 'TAB'!F2:F ='A'or 'B' or 'C'`, count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''",0))`

but probably because of obvious reasons it did not work. Please help me with this one.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Input the criteria in `J1`, which is referred by my formula.

- leave it blank to match all rows
- for single value, simply input it, i.e. `NEW`
- for multiple values, join them with `|`, i.e. `NEW|IN PROGRESS`

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN('RAW-TODOS'!A2:A&"♦"&TRIM(SPLIT('RAW-TODOS'!B2:B,";"))),"♦"),CONCATENATE("select Col2,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null",IF(J1="",," and Col1 matches '"&J1&"'")," group by Col2 label count(Col2) ''"),0))`

Comment: Thank you, however it gave the **"In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows."** error. It looks like the problem is within query column selection and appending the range. Even if I use the original formula and only add try to append `'RAW-TODOS'!F2:F}` it would break. **Is it due to the query syntax?**

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet. Actually I cannot understand what `&{"";""}` is for.

Comment: Here it is in F column : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zwpFJ4tjk05f7cQnJzGzAVsSKdDNi8Jp6pvctHWegzQ/edit#gid=822556773
It takes data from raw todos tab and gives me a table which displays all data. I would like to have a table of data filtered based on a A column in raw todos tab. The marking you wrote is for separating values in one row.

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't put the criteria properly. Cloud you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: Edited. Hope it can help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FILTER('RAW-TODOS'!B:B, 
 REGEXMATCH('RAW-TODOS'!A:A, "NEW|IN PROGRESS")), ";"))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1
  label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, however it gave the **"In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows."** error. It looks like the problem is within query column selection and appending the range. Even if I use the original formula and only add try to append `'RAW-TODOS'!F2:F}` it would break. **Is it due to the query syntax?**

Comment: Here it is in H column : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zwpFJ4tjk05f7cQnJzGzAVsSKdDNi8Jp6pvctHWegzQ/edit#gid=822556773
It takes data from raw todos tab and gives me a table which displays all data. I would like to have a table of data filtered based on a A column in raw todos tab. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: It seems the output is not correct. For example: `t.savukynas@cityprojects.lt` should be `27`.